# Image/text not showing in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I want to create a Window with an image and a text so far i've got this:

```
public void ShowPng1() {
        ImageIcon theImage = new ImageIcon("Icon_Entry_21.gif");
        panel.setSize(270, 270);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(theImage);
        imageLabel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.add(imageLabel);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
```

My panel:

```
private JFrame panel = new JFrame();
```

For some reason it won't load nor image nor text, it just pops up as a white window. What can be the problem? I've also tried changing the format to `.png`, didn't work.

**UPDATE**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Img {

    private JFrame panel = new JFrame();

    public Img(){
        ShowPng1();
    }

    public void ShowPng1() {
        ImageIcon theImage = new ImageIcon("Icon_Entry_21.gif");
        panel.setSize(300, 300);
        panel.setResizable(false);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(theImage);
        imageLabel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.add(imageLabel);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        panel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Img();
    }
}
```

I've managed to get this working, which is ridiculous because I can't figure out how to make it work with my program. Reimeus gave me an idea on creating this script separately, the fix and that worked. I will have to look through my entire program to see if I'm missing anything. Creating it in a separate class should work as well.

Comment: *"it just pops up as a white window"* worries me, this suggest that you have a paint issue and/or are block the EDT. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it just pops up as a white window

Sounds like you're blocking the EDT on startup. You may need to use one of [Swing's concurrency mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to solve it. Post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can determine this for sure.

In the meantime...

You're displacing the component containing the `theImage` component in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` location

```
panel.add(label);
```

You could organize your labels so that they can appear simultaneously (placing the components at 2 different `BorderLayout` locations will do)

```
panel.add(imageLabel);
panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but *"For some reason it won't load nor image **nor** text, it just pops up as a white window"* suggests that something else is a miss...

Comment: Oh, there's nothing wrong with the answer as it's great advice and will fix the "next" problem the OP has after we fix this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a JPanel and add it to the frame, and then add the labels to the panel

Something like

```
 private JPanel panel = new JPanel;
```

and then add it to the frame in your method calling

```
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: Like `private JFrame panel = new JFrame();` which is mentioned in the question?